# how to check whether a particular object mapping exist or not - JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object mapping as `res.payload.data[0].tnxResponse`. So I want check whether `res` has `payload` object and it has `data` and so on. I have tried this, but it throws error.

`let val = res?.payload?.data[0]?.tnxResponse`

Comment: What error does it throw, I mean what is its message ?

Comment: Unexpected token at ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Okay nevermind, telling us the Error message changes things dramatically, who would have thought, make sure to include the error message next time.*

Youre using a version of Node.js or a Browser that is too old and doesnt support optional chaining "?.".

According to [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----) Node.js supports optional chaining from version 14.5.0, and as by [canIUse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) Internet Explorer doesnt support it at all, and all other major browsers support it since early 2020.

So either youre using it in an outdated version of the major browsers, using  internet explorer, or node.js prior to Version 14.5.0. Make sure to update your environment or if tahts not an option use a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code down to an older version of JavaScript.

**Old answer:**

I suppose the error you're getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

You forgot the [optional chaining when accessing the data array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#optional_chaining_with_expressions), what you can do is `data?.[0]`

When your response holds data in the form of `res = { payload: {} }` your expresion will be successfully evaluated until `test?.payload?.data` yielding `undefined` then the array index access is done on `undefined` and throws the error. So in total `res?.payload?.data?.[0]?.tnxResponse` should give you either undefined or the result of `tnxResponse` without throwing an error.

Comment: yes, I have tried it and getting Syntax error:  unexpected token error. for example
`const a = {
    b: {
        c: 'c'
    }
}

console.log(a?.b?.c)`